# Как организовать синхронизацию сайта с репозиторием git?

Tags: svn, bitbucket, git, github

Хочу настроить синхронизацию. Я работаю на локальной машине, заливаю на битбакет, а затем заливаю на сервер (сайт). Опишите инструкцию действий, пожалуйста. Какие команды нужно прописать на сервере, где и какие ключи создать? Буду рад, если опишете подробно.

Comment: Извините, а оно вам надо? А если что то уйдет не то? А вы заметите не сразу.

Comment: А что посоветуешь?

Comment: Я бы посоветовал написать скрипт (sh или bat), который бы выполнял функцию update на сервере.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-git)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Знакомый немного рассказывал как он это организовал, и говорит все достаточно просто. Сам не делал, поэтому опишу очень скудно

На bitbucket создаем событие "при пуше", и отправляем запрос на сервер. Дальше идет обработка на сервере, и идет запись новых файлов.

И еще в дополнение мой [вопрос на руткоде](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/8813/%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-bitbucket-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC)

> Выбирайте свой проект, жмите шестеренку, слева в меню hooks, выбирайте POST, вводите url, там где-то ещё есть дока по параметрам, можете ее читать, а можете просто тестовое изменение сделать и залогировать этот POST. И на основании полученных данных делайте checkout/pull.